# Saving user's DataGridViewColumn widths for multiple forms/controls

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, registry

Typically, when designing a `DataGridView`, I try to size the columns so that nothing will need to be resized by the user.  This practice works most of the time, but I recently had a user change her Windows settings so that text would display larger than usual.

That single act broke all of the tedious sizing that I worked so hard on.  I have looked into saving column width per user and allowing them to be saved to the registry.  The issue I run into is having to create a field in the application settings for each and every value that I want to save to the registry.

When saving settings for a single form, that is not a problem, and I do use the application settings for this purpose to save the main window size/location so that users can determine the optimal view of the application.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to save an array to the registry, or perhaps otherwise save dynamic values into the registry, without adding these values to the application settings in advance?  Ideally, I will just have a "ColumnWidths" application setting or something along those lines, and dynamically add column name/width for any column that is resized by the user.

I have the following code, which is fine if I add a new setting for each individual form that I want to save sizing for, but I'm hoping to achieve this with a single setting, that will save column sizing for multiple `DataGridView`/`Forms`.

```
Private Sub SaveColumnSettings()
    If My.Settings.CustomColumnWidths Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.CustomColumnWidths = New StringCollection
    End If

    For Each dc As DataGridViewColumn In grdBackOrderedItems.Columns
        My.Settings.CustomColumnWidths.Add(dc.Width.ToString())
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub LoadColumnSettings()
    For i As Integer = 0 To My.Settings.CustomColumnWidths.Count - 1
        grdBackOrderedItems.Columns(i).Width = CInt(My.Settings.CustomColumnWidths(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that arrangement is dicey: it assumes one collection fits all DGVs on all forms (that is, the same number of columns for all of them) and you are adding to the Collection everytime you save.  Since you want to save the `users optimal view` you should have one collection per DGV since they might well make col4 on DGVD wider than elsewhere.  Or use a custom class and serialize it.  Also, turn on Option Strict

Comment: thanks for the tip, the code was just an example to give an idea what I am trying to accomplish.. I don't mind saving it separate for every DGV, but is there a way to dynamically add application settings?  My application has probably hundreds of DataGridViews, and some may need to be custom sized, and others not necessarily.. I suppose I can just add the settings one at a time as needed, but I am just looking for a simpler generalized way of accomplishing this

Comment: save each grid to a new collection setting.  I would definitely use a custom class though so that if a grid is *not* customized or not *allowed* to be changed then there is no open slot.  Saving by name would allow this and still be one class serves all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings` allows for a Collection type, however it is a string collection (initial post seemed not to know this).

The current edit is dicey since it assumes one collection will fit all DGVs on all forms (that is, the same number of columns for all of them) and you are only adding to the Collection every time you save - making it larger.  Since you want to save the `users optimal view` you should have one collection per DGV since they might well make col4 on DGVFoo wider than elsewhere.

Rather than adding a collection Setting for each DGV (ie "DGVFooColumns", "DGVBarColumns" etc), which requires each one be hard coded to map to the correct entry, I would use a custom class and serialize it.

Most everything regarding them can be internalized to the class.  This is not a finished class, but a rough out of making one class service any and all DGVs (it should be very close):

```
' for the collection
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

<Serializable>
Public Class GridLayouts

    <Serializable>
    Friend Class GridLayout
        Public Property GridName As String
        Public Widths As New List(Of Integer)

        ' Some Serializers will require a simple ctor
        Public Sub New()
            Widths = New List(Of Integer)
        End Sub

        Public Sub SaveLayout(name As String, dgv As DataGridView)
            ' something the code uses to map them
            ' other than "DataGridView1" of which there may be several
            GridName = name

            ' ToDo: loop thru DGV save widths to Widths
        End Sub
    End Class


    Private mCol As Collection(Of GridLayout)
    Private myFile As String

    Public Sub New(filename As String)
        myFile = filename
        mCol = New Collection(Of GridLayout)
    End Sub

    Private Function IndexOf(grdName As String) As Integer  
        For n As Integer = 0 To mCol.Count - 1
            If grdName = mCol(n).GridName Then
                Return n
            End If
        Next
        Return -1        ' not found

        ' alternatively find by name:
        'Dim item = mCol.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.GridName = grdName)
        'Return item
    End Function

    Public Sub StoreLayout(name As String, dgv As DataGridView)
        Dim ndx As Integer = IndexOf(name)
        If ndx <> -1 Then
            mCol.RemoveAt(ndx)          ' throw away old one
        End If

        Dim grd As New GridLayout
        grd.SaveLayout(name, dgv)
        mCol.Add(grd)

    End Sub

    Public Sub RestoreLayout(name As String, dgv As DataGridView)
        Dim ndx As Integer = IndexOf(name)
        If ndx = -1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For n As Integer = 0 To mCol(ndx).Widths.Count - 1
            ' loop thru grid and set the columns
            ' maybe check that the col sizes are equal
            dgv.Columns(n).Width = mCol(n).Widths(n)
        Next n

    End Sub

    Public Sub Save()
        ' ToDo: Make a backup (?)
        ' Add a Try/Catch and convert to function
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        Using fs As New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
            bf.Serialize(fs, mCol)
        End Using

    End Sub

    Public Sub Load()
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        Using fs As New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Open)
            mCol = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), Collection(Of GridLayout))
        End Using
    End Sub        
End Class
```

**Notes:**
1) The Example has `SaveLayout` at the Class-Item level and `RestoreLayout` at the Collection Level.  I would pick one way or the other not split it.  This is was for illustrative purposes.  I would generally favor the ClassItem Level for both.

2) Rather than the BinaryFormatter, you can use the XML Serializer.  I personally loathe it.

3) Note that the collection class saves/loads its own data.

4) `System.Collections.ObjectModel` is required for `Collection(of T)` and prevent VB from wanting the use the vile `VisualBasic` Collection (which stores only `Object`).

5) Code elsewhere could be optimized so that you only store a layout if they actually change the widths and click something (or have an AutoSaveChanges option).

6) A fair amount is riding on the names being unique so that the layouts can be found.

**Usage**

```
Dim SaveFile As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                                    CompName,
                                    ProgramName,
                                    filename)
 ' e.g C:\Users\Ziggy\MyCompany\ThisProd\GridSettngs.bin

' application-wide collection of grid layouts for this user
Private myGrids As New GridLayouts(SaveFile)
...
myGrids.StoreLayout("Customers", datagridView12)
myGrids.RestoreLayout("Orders", datagridView34)
```

Comment: This should do exactly what I need.  Thank you for going above and beyond and taking the time to help solve this issue.  I think this will give me a good start toward what I am hoping to do.